# Couldn't resolve host name for http://vault.centos.org/centos/8/AppStream/

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, centos8

Every time I run a command on my virtual server, I get the following error  *centos8*

> [root@servers03 ~]# **dnf install epel-release** CentOS Linux 8 -
> AppStream                                          0.0  B/s |   0  B
> 00:00 Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'appstream':
>
> - Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for http://vault.centos.org/centos/8/AppStream/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml
>   [Could not resolve host: vault.centos.org] Error: Failed to download
>   metadata for repo 'appstream': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot
>   download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried

> [root@servers03
> ~]# **yum update -y** CentOS Linux 8 - AppStream
> 0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00 Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'appstream':
>
> - Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for http://vault.centos.org/centos/8/AppStream/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml
>   [Could not resolve host: vault.centos.org] Error: Failed to download
>   metadata for repo 'appstream': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot
>   download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried

**I tried to use the following commands to fix the error, but it didn't work**

```
sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*

sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
```

Comment: Has you executed `yum clean all` after implementing changes?

Answer (score 0):

Based on `[Could not resolve host: vault.centos.org]` it looks like there is some issue with DNS resolver.

Try run the following command: `dig +short vault.centos.org`.
It should return a couple of addresses.

If no, try another domain:
`dig +short redhat.com`. In case this command also returns nothing or report an error it means your resolver doesn't know anything about these domains.

So, the easiest option is to temporary add public DNS:

`sudo echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8 \nnameserver 8.8.4.4" >> /etc/resolv.conf`

After update you may manually delete them or just reboot, resolv.conf should be generated from interface config.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance on IPv6 only VM? If yes - you MUST point the VM to external, dual stack resolver as centos.org nameservers are IPv4 only (which is a big pity given the fact that vault.centos.org is dual-stack).